# Trying to send text message using sp_send_dbmail truncates url in body

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using send_dbmail to send a text message to customers.  This is the following sql:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='5558881234@txt.att.net',
@body='check out this url https://www.someurl.com/directory/blah.aspx',
@subject='I am the subject!'
```

The body gets truncated to "check out this url https://www.someurl.com/directory/blah.as"  (the "px" is removed from the end of the url).

I've ruled out message length as I have tried sending just "www.google.com/test.aspx" and the "px" is removed as well.   Another strange thing, when I try forwarding the text message to myself and add the "px" back on myself, it works.  It also works if I send a email from outlook with the same body.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems strange. Have you tried passing unicode strings, i.e. N'check out this url ....', or silly suggestion, have you tried padding the end of your string with a few whitespace characters, or perhaps a few whitespace characters followed by a period? What happens if the body text doesn't end in .aspx, but ends in anything else such as "this is a test", etc.?

Comment: I have not tried either of those.  I will give both a shot and report back.

Comment: Just tried both unicode & padding the first time around and it worked.  Thanks!